# Java Bean CDI Null Pointer Exception

Tags: jms, javabeans, code-injection

I have a normal java bean which is singleton with jms resource like this :

```
@Resource(lookup="jms/queueConnectionFactory")
  private QueueConnectionFactory myQueueConnFactory;

  @Resource(lookup="jms/myQueue")
  private Queue myMessageQueue;

  private Connection myConn;
  private Session mySession;

  private MessageProducer msgProducer;
  private MapMessage myMsg;

  @PersistenceContext(name="OrderServicePU")
  EntityManager em;

  private static MyProducer msgClientProducer;
```

I tried to inject it to servlet controller but resulted with null pointer exception where the queue and connection factory is not get initialized.

```
@Inject private MyProducer msgProducer;
```

I have beans.xml and glassfish-resources.xml defined.

What wrong with that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem solved by properly configure the JMS resource.